# How to use own custom token instead of gas price in ether?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, tokens, erc-20

I want to make my token and want that the token should be used as gas price. Is that possible,if yes please guide me for the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to natively use a token as price for the miner. However, ERC865 provide an implementation where it's possible to develop a token where the user provide delegate access to its funds, and the service keep a commission in tokens, paying the transaction in Ether to the miner. This way the end user won't need to hold Ether in its wallet

[ERC865 https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865)